# network port registry

Tags: network-scanners

I am planning to build an app which gives information about the network port and the service name for non-opensource based products. Is there a legal implication of building such apps? because someone can know the port on which admin services are running (although the service does authentication before accessing it).

Comment: This would probably vary based on your country. However, there are already lists of ports used by software, including non-opensource products. The question as it stands might be a better fit on Law.SE

Comment: can you please point me to the URL of those list.

Comment: There are loads of them - a quick Google suggested http://www.speedguide.net/ports.php and http://www.adminsub.net/tcp-udp-port-finder but they are by no means the only one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are absolutely no legal implications (in any country) regarding the public information of [IANA (Internet Assigned Numbers Authority)](http://www.iana.org/) and the current registry of [service names & transport protocol port numbers](http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml).

From the manual;

> Port numbers are assigned in various ways, based on three ranges:
>   System Ports (0-1023), User Ports (1024-49151), and the Dynamic and/or
>   Private Ports (49152-65535); the difference uses of these ranges is
>   described in [RFC6335]. System Ports are assigned by IETF process for
>   standards-track protocols, as per [RFC6335].  User Ports are assigned
>   by IANA using the "IETF Review" process, the "IESG  Approval" process,
>   or the "Expert Review" process, as per [RFC6335].  Dynamic Ports are
>   not assigned.

Comment: I am not going to list say port 80 for  HTTP or 443 for HTTPS but more of user ports . example some IBM well known product's ports 10280 - 10285 and their service names.Anyway these are publicaly available through their support sites or manuals. Just wanted to know If I list them in my website is there a privacy violation problem. thanks :)